# Upload multiple files to FTP server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp

I am able to upload a single file and now how do I upload multiple files to FTP server :

Here is the code I am working with:

Private Sub uploadFile(ByVal FTPAddress As String, ByVal filePath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
        'Create FTP request

```
    Try
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress & "/" & Path.GetFileName(filePath)), FtpWebRequest)

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)
        request.UsePassive = True
        request.UseBinary = True
        request.KeepAlive = False

        'Load the file
        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(stream.Length - 1)) {}

        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        stream.Close()

        'Upload file
        Dim reqStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        reqStream.Close()

        MsgBox("Uploaded Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Catch
        MsgBox("Failed to upload.Please check the ftp settings", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    btnUpload.Enabled = False
    Application.DoEvents()
    uploadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFilePath.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    btnUpload.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

This is how I modified but not working:

```
 If Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim f As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        For Each file As IO.FileInfo In f.GetFiles
            Select Case file.Extension.ToLower
                Case ".jpg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png", ".ico"
                    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName, CheckState.Checked)
            End Select
        Next
        For pix As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            btnUpload.Enabled = False
            Application.DoEvents()
            uploadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFilePath.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
            btnUpload.Enabled = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
For Each _____ in ______ collection
uploadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFilePath.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
Next
```

(filling-int he blanks depends on whatever control you're using to store the file names in.)

Comment: When I am uploading each time I am getting file uploaded message and when it's not being uploaded I have given exceptional messages can you say how to modify so that When all the Images uploaded I need to get "Uploaded" and when not done it should give me a message "uploading Failed"

Comment: A few ways you could do it, but one you might try is to put your for-each loop inside of a try-catch block.  In the Catch section, you can decide whether to exit the loop and display an error message, or to simply skip that file and log the error, or whatever you think is most appropriate.  As for the success message, I'd just get rid of that, or else put it in the Finally section of the try-catch block.

Comment: Yes I have done it before but it takes too long for the process but if I don't keep the for each loop inside try catch block it takes few seconds to upload everything.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you are gathering your list of files, simply iterate over a collection.

I'll just assume a string for example's sake:

```
Dim files As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Each file In files
  uploadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, file, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
Next
```

Also, consider the `using` statement for objects that implement `IDisposable`.

```
 Private Sub uploadFile(ByVal FTPAddress As String, ByVal filePath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) 'Create FTP request

        Try
            Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress & "/" & Path.GetFileName(filePath)), FtpWebRequest)

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)
            request.UsePassive = True
            request.UseBinary = True
            request.KeepAlive = False

            Dim buffer As Byte() = Nothing
            'Load the file
            Using stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
                buffer = New Byte(CInt(stream.Length - 1)) {}
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            End Using

            'Upload file
            Using reqStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            End Using

            MsgBox("Uploaded Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch
            MsgBox("Failed to upload.Please check the ftp settings", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```